# MongoDB/Mongoose orderby date and groupby user

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection where multiple documents may have the same `userId` field. I would like to groupby `userId` so that I get a list of unique `userId`s, but also a sort by `date` so that each returned document is the latest document for that `userId`. I've done queries like this with sql, and I'm really hoping its possible with mongo.

In this example collection:

```
{ userId: 456, date: 5/16/1988 },
{ userId: 456, date: 5/17/1988 },
{ userId: 789, date: 5/18/1988 },
{ userId: 789, date: 5/17/1988 }
```

I would want to return:

```
{ userId: 456, date: 5/17/1988 },
{ userId: 789, date: 5/18/1988 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the data type of your date-field? I really hope it's not a string formated that way, because that would be impossible to sort. A YYYYMMDD formated string would be possible to sort because alphabetic sorting would work. A numeric value representing an epoch (number of seconds/minutes/days/whatever passed since fixed point in time) would be even better. But the ideal solution would be Ideally it would be of the actual BSON Date type, because you can do much more with it than just sorting it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you would do it in mongo. Note that it got this to work with a date format of yyyy-mm-dd.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    id : '$userId',
    date: { $max: '$date'} 
  }
})
```

Sources: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/

Comment: Is there a way to add this to the options field in a mongoose find query?

Comment: Would love for it to look like this: `Model.find({}, "", { $group: {id: "$userId", date: { $max:"$date" }} })`. It doesn't seem to work this way though.

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp Checkout the Mongoose documentation on [Model.aggregate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate)

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp you don't use Model.find(), you have to use Model.aggregate() [see the doc here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate-js)

Comment: Well this probably does the trick, but I actually can't use it because the established pattern where i wanted to use it is Model.find(). Thanks anyways though.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say you want the full document returned. You can do this by returning the full document as a field in the `$group` operator.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {$sort:{date:-1}},
  {$group: {_id: "$userId", doc:{$first: "$$CURRENT"}} }
])
```

I created four documents like in your question with [Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) type as some random dates. This would give you the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : 789,
    "doc" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53d80e246ebc37d0c33321ba"),
        "userId" : 789,
        "date" : ISODate("2014-07-05T04:00:00.000Z")
    }
}, 
{
    "_id" : 456,
    "doc" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53d80e246ebc37d0c33321b8"),
        "userId" : 456,
        "date" : ISODate("2014-07-05T04:00:00.000Z")
    }
}
```

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#variables for more info on `$$CURENT`

Comment: gah i want this to work but mongoose is not liking $$CURRENT. I get this when I run this query: `"exception: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'."`

Answer (score 0):

Although they probably are the right way to go, I wasn't able to use the db.collection.aggregate methods because I need to use other things like .populate() on a Model.find in this situation. So I came up with a work around where I sort on userID and date in the find(options) like so:

```
{ sort: { updateDate: -1, userId: -1 } }
```

Then I wrote a function on the front end to extract the latest record for each user:

```
filterLatest: function(docs) {
    var lastUserId = null;
    var latestDocs = [];

    docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        if(lastUserId != doc.userId) latestDocs.push(doc);
        lastUserId = doc.userId;
    });

    return latestDocs;
}
```